# Corcel/Laravel package concept

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I am going through a project that uses Corcel package to get the data from a Wordpress database. What I don't understand is when I was going through the code is, that for a route:

```
Route::get('wp', function () {
    return Corcel\Post::find(106);
});
```

I get the data from the Database, event though there is no Post model set up in Laravel. 
I got the same data even when I just used:

```
return Post::find(106);
```

So, I thought that with Corcel package we can just use the name of the model for the table we want to get the data from and it will work without defining the model in Laravel first, since this example works.
But, then I have tried querying options table. Like so:

```
    Route::get('wp', function () {
        return Corcel\Option::all();
    });
```

But, I got:

> FatalThrowableError in routes.php line 25: Class 'Corcel\Option' not
>   found

And if I do:

```
return Corcel\Options::all();
```

Since that is the name of the class in the Corcel package, I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'middleton.options' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `options`)

So, then it tries to do the query in the laravel db and not in the Wordpress db
So, if anyone could explain me how this works I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The class is called Options, not Option, so it would be:

```
Route::get('wp', function () {
    return Corcel\Options::all();
});
```

The method `all()` should work since [it extends](https://github.com/corcel/corcel/blob/master/src/Model.php#L20) from the Laravel Eloquent base Model class. Anyway the class seems to have a method `getAll()` that should return a more comprehensive output ([link](https://github.com/corcel/corcel/blob/master/src/Options.php#L88)).  Try it like this:

```
Route::get('wp', function () {
    return Corcel\Options::getAll();
});
```

Hope this helps you.

**Edit:** Seems that was a [version issue](https://github.com/corcel/corcel/issues/282#issuecomment-309709630) for working with legacy code.

Comment: I have tried that already but then I get: ```SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'middleton.options' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `options`)```  so, then it tries to do the query in the laravel db and not in  the Wordpress db

Comment: @Leff That may be worth posting like an issue in the repo page.

Comment: @Leff  You should try the `getAll()` method. It's supposed to return a more readable output, but it also uses Eloquent `all()` method under the hood so chances aren't with you.

Comment: @Leff Well, then you should post an issue and if you feel like it submit a PR, but clearly looks like a package bug to me.

Comment: @Leff No problem, I'll track the issue and update the answer with useful info about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that since I was working on the legacy code, I didn't have the latest version of the package, where this was fixed.